# Advanced Regex Query?

Tags: regex

I've been in the regexr editor for some time trying to figure this out but I fear I need more time and experience to figure this out on my own and I need to get this done soon...

Here is an example of what I need to validate. I found a simple way to do it but the flaw with it is it supports too much.

#### Requirements

- Must support comma separated list of numbers
- Must support ranges with a hyphen in between them.
- It can't end with a comma

The following patterns below are valid. I need to support the following input

- 1,2,3 <--- This is valid
- 12-14,12 <-- This is also valid
- 1a,2-3,3 <-- NOT VALID

I found a query in the RegExr community for a comma separated list of numbers and I was trying to edit it to see what I could do but I'm stuck. I found a way to do some basics and try and it would work but it allows too much in between. I believe I don't know enough about capture groups  and ranges to make this work.

Here's what I tried.

- available from the community

```
/^[1-9]([0-9])?(,[1-9]([0-9])?)*$/
```

- What I came up with

```
(^([0-9]).*([0-9])$)
```

I realize what I did wrong but once again, I'm in a bit of a time crunch and don't want to be stuck on this for two days. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What language are you implementing this in? JS, Python, ..?

Comment: Would something like `^\d+(?:[,-]\d+)*$` be sufficient? See the demo: https://regex101.com/r/HCKgtB/1

Comment: And to prevent two consecutive hyphens, you may use `^\d+(?:(?:,|-(?!\d+-))\d+)*$` (assuming your regex engine supports Lookaheads). Demo: https://regex101.com/r/HCKgtB/2

Comment: I will be using typescript to implement the regex on the input value of a vueitfy text-field.

Comment: how to go about that problem: you start with the first element: start of string. That's `^`. Then you enlarge what you are matching: start of string and a single digit. That's `^[0-9]`. You enlarge again: to a number consisting of *at least* one digit. That's `^[0-9]+`. Next thing: a minus: append a `-`. Next thing: another number: append the number regex from before. However the minus followed by another number are optional: put the minus and the number inside `()` which groups them and qualify with `?` which means zero or one occurences. Now you can match 123-456.

Comment: Next comes a comma and once again the first pattern we have just defined, again zero or more times aka `?`. This is how you'd find the solution step by step. @AhmedAbdelhameed 's solution is more compact but also harder to understand, since it's using more tools (that's why I didn't verify it)

Comment: I am guessing that your problem is the following, "How do I determine if string contains only comma-separate tokens, where each token consists of one or more digits or a pair of one or more digits separated by a hyphen. Moreover, each string of digits cannot begin with a zero. Therefore, the string contains only digits, commas an hyphens." Is that correct? In any event you need to begin your question with a complete, unambiguous statement of the problem. You should also strip out all the irrelevant bumf, such as the first sentence, and replace the title with something meaningful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
^[1-9]\d*(?:-[1-9]\d*)?(?:,[1-9]\d*(?:-[1-9]\d*)?)*$
```

https://regex101.com/r/cgZbfk/2

Which is equivalent to the less repetitive

```
^(?<item>(?<d>[1-9]\d*)(?:-\g<d>)?)(?:,(\g<item>))*$
```

(if your engine supports named capture groups and recursion)

- `(?<item>(?<d>[1-9]\d*)(?:-\g<d>)?)` - Match an "item", one of the parts between the commas:

  - `(?<d>[1-9]\d*)` - Match a valid digit (begins with 1 to 9 and may have more digit characters)
  - `(?:-\g<d>)?` Optionally match a `-` followed by another valid digit
- `(?:,(\g<item>))*` - Then match zero or more times:

  - `,(\g<item>)` - A comma, followed by another "item"

Anchored to the start and end of the string with `^` and `$`.

That's if you actually need to validate that a number doesn't start with a 0. If a number starting with a 0 is OK (or won't happen), you can just use `\d+` instead, [`^(?<item>\d+(?:-\d+)?)(?:,\g<item>)*$`](https://regex101.com/r/cgZbfk/3), equivalent to `^(\d+(?:-\d+)?)(?:,\d+(?:-\d+)?)*$` without the named group and recursion.

Comment: Thank you so much. If you don't mind my asking, where do you recommend to get the best training over regex? I view this as essential for string manipulation and validation. I intend on improving and I don't mind asking for help but try to figure it out on my own as best I can.

Comment: First familiarize yourself with the syntax, if you aren't already - check out examples, and whenever you don't understand a construct, look it up. Then, like with many programming-related subjects, a decent option is to watch Stack Overflow questions and try to come up with answers. Watch to see how others answer too. Repeat a bunch of times and you'll have gotten some experience.

Comment: All that I can add to that advice is to become familiar with online regex testers, especially regex101.com, which supports the main regex engines, provides a detailed explanation of each token in the regex and supports substitutions.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is the OP wishes to determine if string contains only comma-separate tokens, each token consisting of one or more digits or a pair of one or more digits separated by a hyphen, with each string of digits beginning with a digit other than zero.

Assuming the language has a PCRE-flavoured regex engine (PHP, for example), the following regex could be used:

```
^(?!0|.*,0)(\d+(?:-\d+)?)(?:,\g<1>)+$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/NugEFk/1/)

The regex could be made self-documenting by writing it in *free-spacing* mode:

```
/
^           # match beginning of a line
(?!         # begin a negative lookahead
  0         # match '0' at the beginning of a line
  |         # or  
  .*,0      # match 0+ characters in the same line (.*) then ',' then '0'
)           # end negative lookahead
(           # begin capture group 1
  \d+       # match 1+ digits
  (?:-\d+)  # match '-' followed by 1+ digit in a non-capture group
  ?         # make the non-capture group optional 
)           # end capture group 1
(?:         # begin a non-capture group
  ,         # match ','
  \g<1>     # invoke capture group 1 as a sub-expression
)           # end non-capture group
+           # execute non-capture group 1+ times
$           # match end of line
/x          # free-spacing mode
```

The negative lookahead ensures that no group of digits begins with a zero. It's not strictly necessary, but it avoids the need later to have `\d` is some places and `[1-9]` in others--I can simply use `\d` everywhere.

If the language being used does not support sub-expressions replace `\g<1>` with the non-capture group `(:\d+(?:-\d+)?)` and (optionally) convert the capture group to a non-capture group.

If the string consists of a single line the begining- and end-of-line anchors can be replaced by the beginning- and end-of-string anchors, `\A` and `\z`.